I'm getting an unexpected value when using the isalpha() function in c++
I am writing a program to count how many letters, numbers, and special characters are in a string but have stumbled across a problem when counting letters.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    int numbers,
        letters, 
        other;

    cout << "Please type in a sentence: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);

    for(int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++)
    {
        if(isalpha(sentence[j])){
            letters++;
        }
        else if(isdigit(sentence[j])){
            numbers++;
        }
        else{
            other++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of Letters: " << letters << endl;
    cout << "Number of Numbers: " << numbers << endl;
    cout << "Number of Everything Else: " << other << endl;

    return 0;
}

This is my code, everything else seems to work just fine. My issue is that for some reason the letter count starts at 26 and goes up from there. Is there something wrong with the other parts of my code that could be causing that issue or am I just using the function the wrong way?
The only think I can think that it is doing is counting every letter in the alphabet and then going from there because why in the world is it starting from 26? Any help is much appreciated!

int numbers, letters, other; are all not initialised.  Reading from an uninitialized variable eg letters++; is Undefined Behaviour.  If you set your compiler warnings high enough - live - https://godbolt.org/z/GPThG1Y9o - the compile should warn you.

Turn up your compiler warnings, it should tell you about this.

You don't initialize any of the variables before using them. Repeat after me: I will always initialize variables before using them. I will always initialize variables before using them. I will always initialize variables before using them. Repeat until you don't stand a chance of forgetting, and then always initialize variables before using them.

As often, valgrind is your friend and would tell you at runtime something like Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s), but it is even better as mentionned by other comments that it can be detected at compilation time with the correct compilation options.

@edrezen valgrind is great, but that's one of the most inscrutible messages, especially for newbies.

@RichardCritten thank you so much! I'll be sure to turn my compiler warnings high enough from now on.

@KenWhite lol I will always initialize variables before using them. I need to get in the habit of doing so before this becomes the source of all my woes.

Tactical note: A lot of new programmers assume int numbers, letters, other = 0; will initialize numbers, letters and other to 0, but C++ is more literal than that. Only other got zeroed.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

@tacettark The interesting thing to me is why you thought that just declaring your variables would initialise them to zero. Can you explain that? It seems to be a mistake that a lot of beginners make.

The issue you're encountering is that the variable letters (as well as numbers and others) are not initialized. In C++, if you don't initialize these variables, they can have unpredictable (garbage) values, which could explain why the count starts at 26.
To fix this, you must initialize numbers, letters, and others to 0 at the program's start. Here's the corrected version of your code:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    int numbers = 0,    // Initialize variables to 0
        letters = 0, 
        other = 0;

    cout << "Please type in a sentence: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);

    for(int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++)
    {
        if(isalpha(sentence[j])){
            letters++;
        }
        else if(isdigit(sentence[j])){
            numbers++;
        }
        else{
            other++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of Letters: " << letters << endl;
    cout << "Number of Numbers: " << numbers << endl;
    cout << "Number of Everything Else: " << other << endl;

    return 0;
}

By initializing the variables to 0, you ensure that the counting starts correctly from zero, and your program should now count letters, numbers, and special characters as expected.
